# C Structure typedef with Forward Declarations

Tags: c

I was using typedef for structures everywhere in my application. I then started to refactor into several
header files when it started to get clunky. I noticed I needed to forward declare Object, and Klass.
Well, to my surprise, I couldn't forward declare Object, or Klass. This is because, as you can see in the
Object and Klass structure, I'm using a typedef of Object and Klass.

```
//Klass.h

typedef struct Klass Klass_t;

struct Klass
{
    void (*_initialize)(Object_t* object, Klass_t* klass);
};

//Object.h

typedef struct Object Object_t;

struct Object
{
    Klass_t* _klass;
};
```

At first, using typedef was great. But trying to forward declare Object:

```
struct Object_t;
```

Doesn't work as I would need to rewrite by function declarations as:

```
void (*_initialize)(struct Object_t* object, Klass_t* klass);
```

So I decided to just typedef Object inside the Klass.h header file:

```
typedef struct Object Object_t;
```

Well when all header files are included into my Main.c file, it complians:

```
Object.h:5: error: redefinition of typedef 'Object_t'
```

So, I then decided to just drop all struct typedefs and explicity declare my structures.

Is there a way to typedef a structure and forward declare in another file without explicitly using struct Object?

I want to keep structure typedefs inside the header file where
the structure is declared. If I have to group all typedefs inside one header file then I would rather not use typedef at all. Anyways, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that a `typedef` is just an alternative name for a type.  There's a reason the Linux kernel doesn't use `typedef`s for structure types, and you're demonstrating it.

There are a couple of ways around your problem.  I note that C11 does allow multiple occurrences of the same `typedef`, but I'm assuming you're stuck with an older compiler that does not support that.

#### TL;DR

Even though the Linux kernel doesn't use `typedef`s, I usually *do* use `typedef`s, but I mostly avoid mutually referential structure types (I can't think of any code where I used such a type).  And, like [Jens Gustedt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366377/jens-gustedt) notes in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21515144/15168), I almost invariably use the notations:

```
typedef struct SomeTag SomeTag;
```

so that the type name and the structure tag are the same (they're in different namespaces).  This operation is not necessary in C++; when you define `struct SomeTag` or `class SomeTag`, the name `SomeTag` becomes a type name without the need for an explicit `typedef` (though a `typedef` does no harm other than revealing that the author is more experienced in C than C++, or the code originated as C code).

I also observe that names starting with an underscore are best treated as 'reserved for the implementation'.  The rules are a little more complex than that, but you run a risk of the implementation usurping your names — and being within its rights to usurp your names — when you use names starting with an underscore, so don't.  Likewise, POSIX reserves type names ending `_t` for the implementation if you include any POSIX headers (such as `<stdio.h>` when you aren't compiling in strict Standard C only mode).  Avoid creating such names; they'll hurt you sooner or later.  (I've not fixed the code below to deal with either of these issues: *caveat emptor*!).

In the code fragments below, I'm mostly ignoring the code that prevents multiple inclusions (but you should have it in your code).

### Extra header

#### typedefs.h:

```
typedef struct Object Object_t;
typedef struct Klass  Klass_t;
```

#### klass.h

```
#include "typedefs.h"

struct Klass
{
    void (*_initialize)(Object_t *object, Klass_t *klass);
};
```

#### object.h

```
#include "typedefs.h"

struct Object
{
    Klass_t *_klass;
};
```

This works because the two type names `Klass_t` and `Object_t` are declared before they're used.

### Use `struct Object` in prototype

#### klass.h

```
typedef struct Klass Klass_t;
struct Object;

struct Klass
{
    void (*_initialize)(struct Object *object, Klass_t *klass);
};
```

Or, for consistency, it might even use:

```
    void (*_initialize)(struct Object *object, struct Klass *klass);
```

#### object.h

```
#include "klass.h"

struct Object
{
    Klass_t *_klass;
};
```

This works because (within broad limits — basically, if the types are defined at file scope, not inside a function) `struct Object` always refers to the same type, regardless of whether all the details are fully defined yet.

#### GCC 4.8.2

Under all of `-std=c89`, `-std=c99` and `-std=c11`, GCC 4.8.2 accepts replicated `typedef`s, as in the code below.  It requires `-std=c89 -pedantic` or `-std=c99 -pedantic` to get errors about the repeated `typedef`s.

Even without the `-pedantic` option, GCC 4.5.2 rejects this code; however, GCC 4.6.0 and later versions accept it without the `-pedantic` option.

#### klass.h

```
#ifndef KLASS_H_INCLUDED
#define KLASS_H_INCLUDED

typedef struct Klass Klass_t;
typedef struct Object Object_t;

struct Klass
{
    void (*_initialize)(Object_t *object, Klass_t *klass);
};

#endif /* KLASS_H_INCLUDED */
```

#### object.h

```
#ifndef OBJECT_H_INCLUDED
#define OBJECT_H_INCLUDED

typedef struct Klass Klass_t;
typedef struct Object Object_t;

struct Object
{
    Klass_t *klass;
};

#endif /* OBJECT_H_INCLUDED */
```

#### consumer.c

```
#include "klass.h"
#include "object.h"

Klass_t k;
Object_t o;
```

You'll have to decide whether that's a risk you're willing to take for your code — how important is portability, and to which versions of C (and which C compilers) must it be portable.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the `struct` keyword. It should be

```
typedef struct Object Object_t;
```

Forward declaration in that way (but see below) should always be possible. This forward declares the `typedef` identifier and the `struct` tag at the same time.

Just put such forward declarations of *all* your `struct` before the real declarations. As long as you only use pointers to these `struct` inside the declarations everything should be fine, then.

nitpick: names with a `_t` are reserved by POSIX. This means that you should avoid it, because some day on some platform there could be a `Object_t` that is predefined and will conflict with your type.

I personally prefer the following convention

```
typedef struct Object Object;
```

so the word Object, with or without `struct`, always refers to the same.

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea about POSIX. As portability is important to me, I will think of another naming convention.