# Declaration of the two structures and use one in the second

Tags: c, struct

I've got two structures in two different header files, let's say:
**header1.h:**

```
#ifndef HEADER1_H
#define HEADER1_H

#include "header2.h"

typedef struct
{
  Struct2 s;
} Struct1;
#endif
```

**header2.h:**

```
#ifndef HEADER2_H
#define HEADER2_H

#include "header1.h"

typedef struct
{
  Struct1* s;
} Struct2;

#endif
```

As you can see i declare Struct2 in Struct1 and pointer to Struct1 in Struct2. Obviously when i try to compile this it gives me an error: unknown type name ‘Struct1’ or 'Struct2'. Is there any way to do this or i must change my conception?

Comment: Yes, you __must__ change .. _whatever_ ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [C Structure typedef with Forward Declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515096/c-structure-typedef-with-forward-declarations)

Comment: typedef is only a user defined alternative name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to do this, you can, you just need to use partial declarations before really declaring each structure:

header1.h

```
#ifndef _HEADER1_H
#define _HEADER1_H

#include "header2.h"

struct struct1
{
      struct struct2 s2;
};
#endif
```

header2.h

```
#ifndef _HEADER2_H
#define _HEADER2_H

struct struct1;

struct struct2
{
      struct struct1 *s1;
};

#endif
```

Comment: But i want to keep my typedef declaration, so i don't need to type keyword struct every time i use my structure in code.

Comment: You can still use `typedef`, I just removed them for the sake of clarity. It's an awful practice to mask the nature of datatypes...

Comment: Ok, but can i declare struct, not pointer to struct in struct? Cause when i change my code as you write above i get this error: field s has incomplete type.

Comment: I mean i want to declare something like that in struct1: `struct2 s2` not pointer `struct2* s2`. If i declare pointer everything looks ok, but when i declare object i get an error: field s2 has incomplete type.

Comment: Here you go, I made the change so that Struct2 is embedded in Struct1. It will still be ugly.